# API for trust.salesforce.com

Tags: api, trust

Is there a public API available to access the trust.salesforce.com information?

(or)

Is it possible to set up monitors to get automatic updates if there are performance issues/degradation with a particular instance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've set up IFTTT to monitor the trust RSS feed and text me when there are issues. Sometimes I get alerts after the degradation is over because IFTTT runs in batches every 15 or 30 minutes. It still works pretty well to let me know when there is an issue. It makes me look smart when someone asks "is there a problem with Salesforce?"

Try this modifying this recipe: https://ifttt.com/recipes/169172-performance-degradation-on-salesforce-na13

Comment: Awesome exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 8):

There is a public facing API:

https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/docs/

You can make a request such as the following to obtain parseable json with status information, degradation, outage, etc, info:

```
$ curl https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/instances/NA48/status
```

You can also install SalesforceA for either Android or iOS to get access to the latest status, view user information, unlock, freeze/unfreeze, activate/deactivate, reset passwords, etc, from your mobile phone. Salesforce just released a native port of the Android client last week which is nice and fast, too.

Comment: FYI, this link is now broken

Comment: FYI, link is working. I checked today.

Answer (score 7):

In 2016 a number of changes were made to Trust - See [What's New in Trust](https://trust.salesforce.com/en/whats-new-trust/).
There is also an addendum not currently mentioned in that post that they have extended a lifeline to the RSS feed -  https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F930000000XZHr&fId=0D53A00002tvoVk

The part of interest for this question is the new [REST API](https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/docs/). In particular you can check the status of a pod/instance with a single GET call.

```
https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/instances/na5/status

{
  "key": "NA5",
  "location": "NA",
  "environment": "production",
  "releaseVersion": "Winter '17 Patch 13.5",
  "status": "OK",
  "Incidents": [
    {
      ...
      ],
      "serviceKeys": [
        "coreService"
      ]
    },

  ],
  "Maintenances": [
    ...
  ]
}
```